# Reference template as html page using Razor instead of hard coded string

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am using this https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ as a guide.

This code:

```
using RazorEngine;
using RazorEngine.Templating; // For extension methods.

string template = "Hello @Model.Name, welcome to RazorEngine!";
var result =
    Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```

Instead of using `string template` ... is it possible to reference it to a `index.html` file to use as a template?

This is how the HTML file looks like..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="header" style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="color: red;">Hello @Model.Name</p>
    </header>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is a string, regardless of where it came from.  You can use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext) to read a file as a string.  For example:

```
string template = File.ReadAllText("index.html");
var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "templateKey", null, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: How can I reference multiple data? like this? `new { Name = "World"}, { New = "Test"} `

Comment: @XMLtoPDF: You can add multiple properties to the anonymous object: new { Name = “World”, New = “Test” }